# capybara fill_in sometimes doesn't fill in all the characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, capybara

About 3 in 10 times, this spec will fail because `fill_in` fails to fill in all of the characters of the `user[username]` field.

```
uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
fill_in "user[username]", :with => uuid
```

Notes:

- Sometimes it succeeds
- Sometimes it drops a random number of characters, usually somewhere after index 29
- never fails locally on OSX
- failures happen remotely on Solano aka tddium

Does anyone know what is going on?

### This is my configuration:

```
capybara (2.4.4)
selenium-webdriver (3.0.0)
ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e) (very recent)
using Chrome, not headless:
```

And in spec_helper:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  http_client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  http_client.timeout = 100
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :http_client => http_client)
end
```

Comment: First make sure the latest chromedriver is being used.  Other than that, are you applying any JS widgets to the element that's being filled in, and if so are you making sure the widget has actually been applied before the field gets filled in?

Comment: There is no JS being applied to these fields. chromedriver is version ChromeDriver 2.25.426924 (649f9b868f6783ec9de71c123212b908bf3b232e)

Comment: Sounds like you're running into this chromedriver issue - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1506&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: That does look like it. Not sure, but maybe latest version of capybara takes care of this?

Answer (score 1):

@thomas-walpole probably is pointing out the root cause - a change in chromedriver that was not compensated for by a change in capybara as we had pegged that gems version number at 2.4.4.

I upgraded capybara to the latest version, 2.10.1, fixed all the necessary deprecations, and retested.

Somewhere in there, it seems to work now. At least, where as I used to get 3 failures in 10 tries, now it works consistently for at least 20 repetitions.